# Octaplanner example for Capicated Vehicle Routing with Time Window?

Tags: optaplanner

I am new to OctaPlanner.
I want to build a solution where I will nave number of locations to deliver items from one single location and also I want to use openmap distance data for calculating the distance.

Initially I used jsprit, but for more than 300 deliveries, it takes more than 8 minutes with 20 threads. Thats why I am trying to use Octa planner.
I want to map 1000 deliveries within 1 minute.

Does any one know any reference code or reference material which I can start using?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

CVRPTW is a standard example, just open the examples app, vehicle routing and then import one of the belgium datasets with timewindows. The code is in the zip too.

To scale to 1k deliveries and especially beyond, you'll want to use "Nearby selection" (see reference manual), which isn't on by default but which makes a huge difference.